# Pandas to_datetime adds year 1900 while I specified format to month day and time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This is basically my code :

```
    for index in range(scen_1['DateTime'].size):
        DateandTime = scen_1['DateTime'][index][1:3] + '-' + scen_1['DateTime'][index][4:6] + ' ' + scen_1['DateTime'][index][8:]
        if '24:00:00' in DateandTime:
            DateandTime = DateandTime.replace('24:00:00','00:00:00')
        scen_1['DateTime'][index] = DateandTime

scen_1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(scen_1['DateTime'], format='%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

So I get this result:

```
             DateTime  OutdoorTemp  ...  HeadOfficeOcc                Date
0      01-01 00:15:00          NaN  ...              0 1900-01-01 00:15:00
1      01-01 00:30:00          NaN  ...              0 1900-01-01 00:30:00
2      01-01 00:45:00          NaN  ...              0 1900-01-01 00:45:00
3      01-01 01:00:00       5.2875  ...              0 1900-01-01 01:00:00
4      01-01 01:15:00          NaN  ...              0 1900-01-01 01:15:00
...               ...          ...  ...            ...                 ...
17371  06-30 23:00:00      19.9875  ...              0 1900-06-30 23:00:00
17372  06-30 23:15:00          NaN  ...              0 1900-06-30 23:15:00
17373  06-30 23:30:00          NaN  ...              0 1900-06-30 23:30:00
17374  06-30 23:45:00          NaN  ...              0 1900-06-30 23:45:00
17375  06-30 00:00:00      17.8250  ...              0 1900-06-30 00:00:00
```

any help is very much appreciated, I tried dt.date dt.time and I don't what else to try thanks !

Comment: why do you have to change the datetime data?  It seems like a bad practice.  What is the desired output

Comment: Dates require minimally a year, month, _and_ day. If any element is missing the default is provided. Year defaults to 1900, month defaults to January, and day defaults to 1. There is no way to have a datetime without at least those three components.

Comment: Yes I realized that I shouldn't be bothering myself with trying to do this, I just set the DateTime column as index. Thanks for your replies anyways much appreciated!